# Remaining Balance Formula for Actual/360 and Actual/Actual Accrual Methods

Tags: debt

Is there a concise formula for calculating the remaining balance of a loan with actual/360 and actual/actual accruals?

I know for 30/360 amortizations, the remaining balance is just the FV of the principle less the FV of the loan payment annuity.

```
// Remaining balance for a loan amount of "princ" 
// and a monthly payment of "coupon" using a 30/360 accrual

Remaining Balance = princ * (1+r)^n - coupon * [((1+r)^n - 1) / r]
```

I know with actuals, we can't easily use the annuity formula, since we don't have level payments.

I was hoping there was a formula that can take into account these "errors", where the annuity assumes 30 day, missing the day in 31, compound the error at the same rate, allowing us to still calculate the accurate remaining balance.

Or do we have to build a full amortization schedule to compute?

For a refresher on accrual methods, [here is a terrific blog post explaining the differences](https://propertymetrics.com/blog/30-360-vs-actual-360-vs-actual-365/)

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to derive formula that is so short. The reason that the formula for 30/360 is so short is that every payment is the same and can be gathered into $(1+r)^n$, for ACT/360 you would unfortunately have $(1+r1)^k (1+r2)^m ...$ etc. But if you want approximate formula (rather than the exact) then short formula is probably achievable.

Comment: Right - the problem is that the monthly amount is not fixed. My thought was, even though the month to month isn't fixed, the "error" or days missed by assuming 30 instead of actual *is known*. If we can compound that error at the same rate, we should be able to fix the bias of using 30/360. That was the thought.